# URISyntaxException: Invalid % sequence

Tags: java, android, uri, ipv6

I am new to IPv6, When I am trying create a URI using IPv6, I encountered this exception. The full exception is

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Invalid % sequence: %wl in authority at index 32: tcp://[fe80::ceb8:a8ff:fe23:5b84%wlan0]:1883
at libcore.net.UriCodec.validate(UriCodec.java:58)
at java.net.URI.parseURI(URI.java:394)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:204)
```

I code I use looks like this

```
String ipv6 = "tcp://[fe80::ceb8:a8ff:fe23:5b84%wlan0]:1883";
URI uri = new URI(ipv6);

SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(uri.getHost()), 1883);
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(sockaddr);
```

The above code works without any exception in Samsung Galaxy S5 running Android 7.1.1, but not Asus Zenfone GoTV and Android emulator running Android 5 and 6.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The % character is a special character in URLs and needs to be escaped. Actually, % is the escape character. You can escape it as `%25`:

```
String ipv6 = "tcp://[fe80::ceb8:a8ff:fe23:5b84%25wlan0]:1883";
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work: On my computer Java would interpret this as "network card named '25wlan0'".

Comment: That's a bug in java then. I'm not sure you can do anything about that... :(